# How to make a java method with a dynamic number of arguments which is set at compile-time (lombok-like behavior)

Tags: java, methods, parameters, enums, parameter-passing

I want to make a Message enumeration with each message being on enum type to avoid errors with typos in the message keys. I also want to use parameters (like `#{0}`) to be able to insert names and more information. 
To make things a lot easier, I would like to add the method `get`, that has a dynamic number of (string typed) arguments - one for each parameter that I want to replace. The exact number of arguments should be set at compile-time and is defined by a field of that enum value.

Consider this enumeration:

```
public enum Message {
    // Written by hand, ignore typos or other errors which make it not compile.

    NO_PERMISSION("no_permission", 0),
    YOU_DIED("you_died", 1),
    PLAYER_LEFT("player_left", 2);

    private String key;
    private int argAmount;

    Message(String key, int argAmount) {
        this.key = key;
        this.argAmount = argAmount;
    }

    public String replace(String... args) {
        String message = get();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            message.replace("#{" + i + "}", args[i]);
        }

        return message;        
    }

    public String get() {
        return myConfigFileWrapper.getMessage(key);
    }
}
```

When I want to retrieve a message, I use `Message.YOU_DIED.replace(myInformation)`. However, I would have to lookup how many arguments the `YOU_DIED` message takes, and if there are multiple, I would need to take a look at the config file to see which index belongs to which parameter type.

To clarify this, here is an example: 
The `PLAYER_LEFT` message is broadcasted to all players and tells them that player x has left with a score of y. In my .lang file, one would find `player_left= The player #{0} left with the score #{1}!`. In the source code, I will then need to use `Message.PLAYER_LEFT.replace(name, score)`. When my enum is extended now, I probably have more than 100 messages. 
This means I simply can not remember if the message was `The player #{0} left with the score #{1}!` or `The player #{1} just left!`.

My goal is that the compiler automatically throws an error when the `get` method is not given the exact amount of arguments it needs. This also means that my IDE autocompletion feature will tell me how many arguments to pass.

As you can see, at the moment I am using varargs to inject the variable information into the message. Why I want to take this a step further should be clear by now. I know that this is a kind of luxury feature, but I am only learning and have no one that expects some sort of result at some time.

One approach would be a Message class with tons of subclasses overriding the original get method with a set number of arguments: `get(String name, String score)`. However, this would make a horrible mess with billions of subclasses - one for each message. I didn't even try to create this sort of Message class(es). Also, using this way would require a lot effort to 'create' all the messages and then later to add new ones.

Next, I looked over the reflection API to make this work, but as soon as I figured that reflection wouldn't work for dynamic compile-time methods, I went on. And as far as I know, actually creating new dynamic methods (and that is what I try to do, basically) is not possible especially as one couldn't use them via normal calls because the method wouldn't exist at compile-time.

The only application doing this thing I know so far is Lombok. Lombok uses annotations which are replaced with byte code at compile-time. I took a look into the source code, but just the core itself is pretty big and has cross dependencies everywhere which make it hard to really understand what is going on.

**What is the best and easiest way to generate these methods with a dynamic argument number *set at compile-time*? And how does that said way work?**

Code snippets and links to pages with further information are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trying to do this in a way like Lombok (annotations/internal API) will mostly be more trouble than it's worth. You will need to learn new APIs, spend hours upon hours building a code generator and end up with a result that's not much better than something you could build without code generation. Especially true if you want to do it exactly like Lombok which uses obscure methodology few people know about.

Comment: That said, if you have a burning desire to learn code generation with annotations, start here: https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/annotation-types/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many hours of reading and experimenting, I now finally got my own Annotation Processor and Source Code Generator.

Thanks to @biziclop, @bayou.io and @Aasmund Eldhuset for 3 very different as well as great answers to this question explaining smart approaches. This answer is accepted because it is the approach the OP (me) finally used. If you do not want to put as much work into your project as I did, consider looking at them also.

I followed the guide @Radiodef posted in his comment and everything worked great until I got to the point where he explained how to integrate the annotation processor with maven. After some difficulties in the beginning using maven and following that guide, it actually turned out, Apache Maven was and is the best Dependency and Build Management Tool to use for this type of Annotation Processing. So if you also read that guide and use maven, I recommend you skip part 2.

But, now, it’s not about which problems occurred but what one has to do to make it work:
The maven dependencies required: *org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7:jar*.

The project setup changes a bit as the actual project with the source will be enclosed in a root container project. This is not necessary but it allows for a cleaner project structure and way more readable POMs.

There are 4 POMs:

- RootProject
- ActualProject
- Annotations
- AnnotationProcessors

As said, the RootProject doesn’t contain any source code nor any files but the other projects in general and therefor its pom is simple:

```
<modules>
    <module>ActualProject</module>
    <module>Annotations</module>
    <module>AnnotationProcessors</module>
</modules>

<!— Global dependencies can be configured here as well —>
```

The ActualProject obviously depends on both the Annotations artifact as well as the AnnotationProcessors artifact. And because the AnnotationProcessors artifact depends on the Annotation project, we get the following order for the maven reactor:

1. Annotations
2. AnnotationProcessors
3. ActualProject

We also need to configure which projects to perform annotation processors on and which not to. The annotation processor itself shall not be executed during its own compilation, therefore add the compiler argument `-proc:none`:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.3</version>
     <configuration>
         <compilerArgs>
             <arg>-proc:none</arg>
         </compilerArgs>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For the actual project, we will also disable annotation processing **the same way** during normal compilation and use the *maven-processor-plugin* together with the *build-helper-maven-plugin*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Run annotation processors on src/main/java sources -->
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <processors>
                    <processor>my.annotations.processors.MessageListProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>target/generated-sources</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The Annotation artifact contains most importantly the annotation with the value field which is of type String and an interface the annotated class has to implement as well.
There are two methods the enum has to implement, which are obviously `String getKey()` and `String[] getParams()`. Following this the enum from the question (Messages) is extended like this:

```
@MessageList("my.config.file.wrapper.type")
public enum Messages implements MessageInfo {

    NO_PERMISSION("no_permission"),
    YOU_DIED("you_died",                "score"),
    PLAYER_LEFT("player_left",          "player_name", "server_name");

    private String key;
    private String[] params;

    Messages(String key, String… params) {
        this.key = key;
        this.params = params;

    @Override
    public String getKey() { return key; }

    @Override
    public String[] getParams() { return params; }

}
```

Next, to our AnnotationProcessor. Of course, we implement `AbstractProcessor` and therefore @Override the process method. The class also registers itself with the annotation `@SupportedAnnotationTypes("my.annotation.type")`. First, we perform some checks against the annotated class. Note that the elements annotated with the annotation are handed in in a set which means there will be a foreach loop. However, it is expected to only find **one** `@MessageList` annotation in one project - ever. This is obviously a potential risk, especially when this is used with an unspecific project. Here, it doesn’t matter as we know how to use the Annotation properly.
(One could extend this processor to collect the messages from multiple enums, but it isn’t needed at all.)

```
for (Element e : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MessageList.class)) {
    if (!(e.getKind() == ElementKind.ENUM)) {
        raiseErrorAt(e, "Can only annotate enum types");
        continue;
    } ... }
```

Next, we would have to check if the annotated class actually implements the interface. Just one little problem: The annotated class isn’t compiled yet. The class object of the MessageInfo interface is obtained quite easily:

```
Class<MessageInfo> messageInfoClass = (Class<MessageInfo>) Class.forName("my.annotations.MessageInfo");
```

Yes, this is indeed an unchecked cast, but we use a constant string value so this won’t result in a ClassCastException. Anyway, let’s compile the annotated class. That means, the annotated class musn’t import any other classes which potentially aren’t compiled yet. It shouldn’t because it only serves as a rich resource and could technically also be a .properties file. Again, also a potential risk, and again, we don’t care because we don’t import anything else.

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

// The convertToPath method just returns "src/main/java/<pathWithSlashes>.java"
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(
    new File("ActualProject/" + convertToPath(element.getQualifiedName().toString())));

// The boolean here defines whether the last separator char should be cut off.
// We need to expand the class path so we might as well leave it there.
String classpath = getCurrentClasspath(false) +
    new File("Annotations/target/Annotations-version.jar").getAbsolutePath();

File outputDir = new File("ActualProject/target/classes/");
Iterable<String> arguments = Arrays.asList("-proc:none",
    "-d", outputDir.getAbsolutePath(),
    "-classpath", classpath);

boolean success = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, arguments, null, compilationUnits).call();

fileManager.close();
```

Finally, the last thing done is to check the value of success and return is it’s false.
Here is the getCurrentClassPath method:

```
private String getCurrentClasspath(boolean trim) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (URL url : ((URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getURLs()) {
        builder.append(new File(url.getPath()));
        builder.append(System.getProperty("path.separator"));
    }
    String classpath = builder.toString();
    return trim ? classpath.substring(0, classpath.length() - 1) : classpath;
}
```

Now, with the annotated class compiled, we can load it:

```
URL classesURL = new URL("file://" + outputDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
// The current class loader serves as the parent class loader for the custom one.
// Obviously, it won’t find the compiled class.
URLClassLoader customCL = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{classesURL}, classLoader);

Class<?> annotatedClass = customCL.loadClass(element.getQualifiedName().toString());
```

So, here is the check whether the annotated enum implements the interface:

```
if (!Arrays.asList(annotatedClass.getInterfaces()).contains(messageInfoClass)) {
    raiseErrorAt(element, "Can only annotate subclasses of MessageInfo");
    continue;
}
```

Now, read the values the pass to the source code generator:

```
MessageList annotation = element.getAnnotation(MessageList.class);
String locals = annotation.value();

// To get the package name, I used a while loop with an empty body. Does its job just fine.
Element enclosingElement = element;
while (!((enclosingElement = enclosingElement.getEnclosingElement()) instanceof PackageElement)) ;
String packageName = ((PackageElement) enclosingElement).getQualifiedName().toString();

ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field field : annotatedClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (!field.isEnumConstant()) continue;

    // Enum constants are static:
    Object value = field.get(null);
    MessageInfo messageInfo = messageInfoClass.cast(value);

    messages.add(new Message(field.getName(), messageInfo.getKey(), messageInfo.getParams()));
}
```

The Message class used here is just a data class with private final fields and respective getter methods. It is found in the annotation artifact, but I am not sure about where to put it.
And that’s it! The Velocity Engine and the Context can now be instanitated and passed the values. The last piece of the puzzle is the Template for the source.
First of all, I created 3 variables but special characters, because I failed terribly at intergrating velocity’s escape tool into my project…

```
#set ($doubleq = '"')
#set ($opencb = "{")
#set ($closecb = "}“)
package $package;
```

The the class body is almost just a foreach loop:

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the Annotation Processor for the project ActualProject.
 */
public abstract class Message {

#foreach ($message in $messages)

#set ($args = "")
#set ($replaces = "")
#foreach ($param in $message.params)
#set ($args = "${args}String $param, ")
#set ($replaces = "${replaces}.replace($doubleq$opencb$param$closecb$doubleq, $param)")
#end
#set ($endIndex = $args.length() - 2)
#if ($endIndex < 0)
#set ($endIndex = 0)
#end
#set ($args = $args.substring(0, $endIndex))
    public static final String ${message.name}($args) {
        return locals.getMessage("$message.key")$replaces;
    }

#end

    private static final $locals locals = ${locals}.getInstance();
}
```

That giant set of Velocity directives may seem a bit weird at first glance, but it is really simple. There are no blank lines because they would actually be generated making the generated file quite messy. So what is done? We iterate over all messages. For each message do:

1. Define two variables of type String, args and replaces
2. For each parameter the message takes do:

   - Append the string „String , „ to the args variable.
   - Append the string „.replace(„{}“, )“ to the params variable.
3. Remove the last comma and space from the args variable. (When there are no parameters for a message, endIndex has a negative value. If that’s the case, set endIndex to 0.)
4. Generate the actual method with the name of the enum constant and the argument string generated in 2 and 3.

   - The method returns the message which is retrieved via the class that handles the different languages with the placeholders replaced.

At the end of the file, we define the instance of the Locals class. My first plan was to use an interface, but that didn’t work out too well, so I just require the class to be a singleton. Third time, this is an other potential risk, third time ignored for the same reason.

Oh, and the raiseErrorAt(Element, String) method you maybe stumbled across is just a wrapper for the imo very long call of `processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, msg, element);`

I hope this helped. The full project is public [here](https://gitlab.com/1Darco1/VaroPlugin). For the commit referenced to in this post, see [here](https://gitlab.com/1Darco1/VaroPlugin/tree/21d2cffb8b1d3a850255425d662e6b802a9c6997).
If there are any questions or improvements, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 4):

You could limit the amount of subclasses by creating one general subclass for each distinct number of parameters:

```
public class Message {
    public static final Message0Args NO_PERMISSION = new Message0Args("no_permission");
    public static final Message1Arg YOU_DIED = new Message1Arg("you_died");
    public static final Message2Args PLAYER_LEFT = new Message2Args("player_left");

    private String key;
    private int argAmount;

    protected Message(String key, int argAmount) {
        this.key = key;
        this.argAmount = argAmount;
    }

    // Same replace() method, but make it protected
}
```

With the subclasses being e.g.:

```
public class Message2Args extends Message {
    public Message2Args(String key) {
        super(key, 2);
    }

    public String replace(String first, String second) {
        return super.replace(first, second);
    }   
}
```

Note that `Message` is no longer an `enum`, but for all practical purposes it works the same way (with some added flexibility such as subclassing), since `enum` is just syntactic sugar for a class whose only instances are contained in its own `public static final` fields.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that even if you know the number of arguments, you still don't know what they should be. Is it `Message.PLAYER_LEFT.replace(name, score)` or `Message.PLAYER_LEFT.replace(score, name)`? Or is it maybe `Message.PLAYER_LEFT.replace(name, lastLocation)`?

To avoid it, you can go one step further and do something like this:

```
public abstract class Message<T> {

    public static final Message<Void> YOU_DIED = new Message<Void>("You died.") {
        @Override
        public String create(Void arguments) {
            return this.replace();
        }
    };

    public static final Message<Player> PLAYER_LEFT = new Message<Player>("Player %s left with score %d") {
        @Override
        public String create(Player arguments) {
            return this.replace( arguments.getName(), arguments.getScore());
        }
    };

    private Message(String template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    private final String template;

    protected String replace( Object ... arguments) {
        return String.format( template, arguments );
    }

    public abstract String create(T arguments);
}
```

Admittedly this is quite verbose, but there are a few things going for it:

1. All messages are typesafe.
2. You can (indeed you have to) use higher level objects, which hopefully carry more meaning. While it's difficult to figure out what should go in the two `String` parameters of `Message.PLAYER_LEFT`, if the only argument is an object of type `Player`, the answer is quite obvious.
3. Further to the above, what if halfway through you want to change the message to display the player's nickname or level too? All you need to modify is the actual message, the callers don't have to know about it.

The big downside of it though is that if you've got complex messages (for example `Message.PLAYER_HIT`, which should take two `Player` type parameters), you've got to write wrapper classes for the parameters (in our examples one that encapsulates both players). This can be quite tedious.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would approach the problem this way, since I'm a strong-type guy

```
public interface Message
{

    public static final Message instance = loadInstance();

    String you_died(Player player);

    String player_left(Player player, int score); 

    // etc. hundreds of them
}

// usage
String x = Message.instance.player_left(player, 10);

// one subclass per language
public class Message_jp implements Message
{
    public String you_died(Player player){ return player.lastName + "君，你地死啦死啦"; }
                                           // or whatever way you like to create a String
    // etc.
}
```

At runtime, you need to load the proper subclass of `Message`.

```
static Message loadInstance()
{
    String lang = conf.get("language"); // e.g. "jp"
    Class clazz = Class.forName("Message_"+lang);  // Message_jp.class
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

This approach embeds all messages in class files, which should be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "load the proper subclass of Message". Wouldn't your solution require to have - next to the interface - one class that implements all the messages? Also, I want to support multiple languages and customizable messages, so therefore I can't embed the messages in the source. That is unfortunately not fine.

Comment: yes, one subclass of Message per language; just like one resource file per language. for language "jp", you load "Message_jp" class.

Comment: if some who's not a java programmer needs to edit the messages, yes, this solution is not good.

Comment: I see! Well, you can make it work with a configuration file. `return myStaticWrapper.getMessage("you_died").replace("placeholder", player.getName());` for example. This is tedious, 'though, and would remove the need of the interface since the different languages would then be handled by the wrapper.

Comment: uh? no. see my edit. - anyways, the main point of this approach is that everything is strongly typed; any mistake is discovered at compile time.